# Problem footcitetext numbering

Tags: beamer, biblatex, citing, footnotes

I'm using `footcitetext` and and `footnotemark` in beamer. The numbering is having some troubles since one footnotemakr is defined normally and the other in the columns environment

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer} \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

\usepackage{amsmath,bm} \usepackage{amssymb} \usepackage{tabularx} \usepackage{multirow} \usepackage{booktabs} \usepackage{esint} \usepackage{graphicx} \usepackage{xcolor} \usepackage{pgfplots} \usepackage{tikz} \usepackage{tikzscale}



\usepackage[style=authortitle,backend=bibtex]{biblatex} \addbibresource{bibliography.bib}



\begin{document}



\begin{frame}{Title}{}

Some text here \footnotemark

\begin{columns}

\column{0.5\textwidth}

\begin{itemize} \item 1 \footnotemark \item 2 \item 3 \end{itemize}

\column{0.5\textwidth}


\begin{itemize} \item item 1 \item item 2 \item item 3  \end{itemize}


\end{columns}

\footcitetext{desantes2020comparative} \footcitetext{site1}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use the `\footcitemark/text` workaround for the footnote which is not inside of the columns:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer} \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

\usepackage{amsmath,bm} \usepackage{amssymb} \usepackage{tabularx} \usepackage{multirow} \usepackage{booktabs} \usepackage{esint} \usepackage{graphicx} \usepackage{xcolor} \usepackage{pgfplots} \usepackage{tikz} \usepackage{tikzscale}



\usepackage[style=authortitle,backend=bibtex]{biblatex} \addbibresource{bibliography.bib}



\begin{document}



\begin{frame}{Title}{}

Some text here \footcite{desantes2020comparative}

\begin{columns}

\column{0.5\textwidth}

\begin{itemize} \item 1 \footnotemark \item 2 \item 3 \end{itemize}

\column{0.5\textwidth}


\begin{itemize} \item item 1 \item item 2 \item item 3  \end{itemize}


\end{columns}

 \footcitetext{site1}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```